# A corollary of Arzela-Ascoli

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, compactness, equicontinuity, arzela-ascoli

The Arzela-Ascoli Theorem says that

> If $X$ is a compact metric space and $F$ a subset of $C(X)$, then $F$ is compact if and only if $F$ is closed, uniformly bounded, and equicontinuous.

My textbook gives the following corollary:

> If $X$ is a compact metric space, and $\langle f_n\rangle_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ a uniformly bounded, equicontinuous sequence in $C(X)$, then some subsequence converges uniformly on $X$.

Can someone explain how this corollary follows? Obviously the **set** of all $f_n$ is itself uniformly bounded and equicontinuous, but why must it be closed?

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle` for $\langle$ and $\rangle$, not `<` and `>`. The latter are *relation* symbols; they look different, and produce different spacing.

Answer (score 5):

The *closure* of the set of all $f_n$ is uniformly bounded and equicontinuous, hence compact by Arzela–Ascoli.

Comment: Why does the subsequence converge uniformly?

Comment: @IntegrateThis That is pretty much by definition. You have a sequence contained in a compact subset of the *metric* space $C(X)$; then it has a subsequence convergent in that metric; but convergence in the standard metric of $C(X)$ *is* nothing but uniform convergence.